# Visual Studio 2022 Edit and Continue Core 6 - Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2022, edit-and-continue

I can't find any rhyme or reason to this issue, other than Edit and Continue is causing delays regularly.

Sure fire way to break it is to edit and continue (!): make a change in a function (.cs file) while stepping through. This will cause a delay of anywhere between 10 to 30 seconds.

Once it does apply the code change, all subsequent F10 (step) have a long delay, freezing Visual Studio in many cases. This also occurs if you F5 and then break again into the function, even though the changes have been applied. This renders it unusable and requires stopping and starting the project.

Our solution is all .Net Core 6, there are 96 projects. I wouldn't consider that particularly large as most of the time I'm running only one of the 6 websites. It all ran fine when it was .Net Framework. Editing and Continuing worked superbly in Visual Studio 2022 when targeting that framework, from the time I started using it at RC.

I have disabled ReSharper to no avail.
I have disabled all virus protection no change.

I can only suspect that it is finding some file changes outside of it's remit.

If anyone has experience with this issue or any other suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Comment: I have the same issue. As a workaround I disabled the Edit and Continue option.
Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Enable Edit and Continue and Hot Reload

Comment: I've solved it by moving to Rider. Works fine and is quicker than VS.

Comment: I've been a die-hard VS user my whole career, but over the years the product runs slower and slower.  Rider is slow to start, and has a HUGE memory footprint (6GB! compared to 2GB for VS) but once it starts it seems pretty quick.  It does Edit and Continue much better and more reliably than VS.